# Canvas drawImage() function not registering inputs from another function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am creating a cropping tool and I have an issue with a drawImage() function inside a function which is receiving parameters from another function like so:

Firstly, my cropImage function crunches the input number from a user and sets the cTop (crop top) and cLeft parameters. Then inputs them into the reDrawImg funciton accordingly.

```
cropImage () {
    let cTop = 300 - this.cropTop;
    let cLeft = 300 - this.cropLeft;

    if(this.cropTop == null) {
        this.reDrawImg(cLeft, null, -this.canvasPositionLeft, -this.canvasPositionTop, this.imageWidth, this.imageHeight);
    }
    else if (this.cropLeft == null) {
        this.reDrawImg(null, cTop, -this.canvasPositionLeft, -this.canvasPositionTop, this.imageWidth, this.imageHeight);
    }
    else {
        this.reDrawImg(cLeft, cTop, -this.canvasPositionLeft, -this.canvasPositionTop, this.imageWidth, this.imageHeight);
    }

    console.log("crop: " + cLeft +"/ " + cTop +"........ crop-default: "+this.cropLeft+ "/ "+this.cropTop)
}
```

Then my reDrawImg is initiated with either cropX, cropY or both filled out:

```
reDrawImg (cropX = null, cropY = null, topX = null, topY = null, imageWidth = this.initialWidth, imageHeight = this.initialHeight) {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    let image = new Image();

    /* Everything is working fine up to this point, where for some reaseon, 
     even when the cropX and cropY are filled out correctly (50,80 for example) 
     and I have tested them with console log. The drawImage just crashes and doesnt 
     re-draw the image with the new parameters.

     Then when I hard code the same values (50,80) into the drawImage function, 
     it works fine.
     So the drawImage function just wont accept my variable values.*/

    this.ctx.drawImage(this.loadedImg,
        cropX, cropY, 
        this.initialWidth, this.initialHeight, 
        topX,topY,
        imageWidth, imageHeight
    );
}
```

Is there something I am missing ?

Comment: Are you sure cropX and cropY are both intergers? Not that they are strings or chars for that matter

Comment: You can't pass `null` to any of drawImage arguments. I already gave you the defaults of drawImage in a previous question, so if in your redrawImg one of the arguments is null, fallback to the default value.

Comment: But when I pass in one of the values (hard code), for example 50 as the cropX parameter, and leave cropY null, it works. I will try with the null = 0, as you suggested.

Comment: @Kaiido So I have tested it but the result is the same. My Image doesnt get re-drawn with the parameters I gave it, instead it disapears from the canvas. 
However, when I hard code the parameters cropX/Y I get the desired result.
I really dont understand it anymore.